# Espresso Test Recorder has detached from the device VM

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I'm new to Android development. I wanted to test my UI using Espresso. So experimenting with `Record Espresso Test`.

Initially it launches my app and goes to login page, when I attempt to type the credential it's dead slow (it's taking more time to type a single letter). Somehow managed to type and hit on login, when I tried to navigate to other screens test is terminated saying:

> Test Recorder has detached from the device VM.

Questions:

1. How can I make typing fast during Espresso test recording?
2. Test Recorder has detached from the device VM.

[image: Test Recorder Prompt]

How to resolve this?

Im currently using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3

Comment: If you are new I strongly recommend you to learn how to do some espresso tests without the test recorder. I've tried the test recorder and it doesn't work well yet and you'll need to know how the espresso code works anyway. Also, it's not so difficult as it seems at first sight.

Comment: Sure , I will try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much for your feedback on the Test Recorder preview. We're actively working on ways to improve it and appreciate all your feedback.

**To answer your questions please see below:**

1. > How can I make typing fast during Espresso test recording?

This is something the team is actively working on improving. The problem is we need to reliably intercept events to be able to do the recording reliably. This is causing some additional latency that's particularly noticeable in events like typing text.

2. > Test Recorder has detached from the device VM

That usually means that the USB is flaky and you need to reconnect it to the device. Just reconnecting the USB cable and clicking resume should resume the recording.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. I didn't connect to any USB device, I'm using inbuilt emulator and even tried with Genymotion

Comment: Does it reproduce every time? In this case, sounds like a bug then. Would you mind filing a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Espresso%20Test%20Recorder%20Bug ?